# Making ArcGIS Attachments compulsory (required) for each feature added?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, attachments, photos

Is there a way to make attachments compulsory. That is, each time a user adds a new point or record, they have to include an attachment. I am exploring the Relationship class (Changing rules within it) but it looks like it can only be applied to subtype. There is no subtype in my feature class. I want to make sure each time a record comes in, there is a picture tag to it.

Comment: If attachments enabled on this feature class, you can add them to any new shape

Comment: I assume that this needs to be done at the data end as you might have more than one client app feeding new records into the service?

Comment: Related Idea: https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/10363

Comment: Yes, I was trying the to add a new field as raster and set is as Allow NULL = No. Apparently the Allow NULL = No will still allow users to save the attribute form (in Desktop Editing/Collector) even though users did not key in anything in the field even for fields like string/date/integer.

Comment: could you please specify how the users enter new points or record ? Is it a standard edit session ? Collector ? disconnected editing ? Also, when do you need to validate (notice : I don't think that it can be done on the fly)?

Comment: Everyone, let's focus on a situation when a user edits a feature class from a geodatabase in ArcMap and all new features that will be created should have an attachment added, otherwise they are not saved. Is it possible to get done without using ArcObjects (or SQL constraints if feature class is stored in a DBMS)?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov if it cannot be done OOTB then I think it would be a useful ArcGIS Idea - thanks for adding your bounty to it.

Comment: I have been exploring a work around it, the simplest way is actually to use Survey123. Users will not be able to save the form when the fields are set as required. It works for all the fields, even attachments or signature box. The down side is the layer is saved as Hosted Feature Service, thus it does not sync to Enterprise GDB. And as far as I know it created a new layer, there is no way to use existing feature class.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to do this, and a [search of ArcGIS Ideas](https://community.esri.com/search.jspa?q=attachments&place=%2Fplaces%2F478947&depth=ALL) did not reveal anyone having already asked for it to be implemented.

Consequently, I think that you should post a new [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).